# SQLite problem - works perfect in the 1.6 emulator - won't work on the phone (2.2) or 2.0+ emulator

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a sqlite database to store playlists for a media player I am developing because of extended feature (rather than using the Content Provider). It works perfectly on the 1.6 emulator but FCs on anything higher than 2.0... what has changed that I need to know about as far as opening databases in SDK 2.0+? Here is the logcat.

> 08-06 19:05:46.365: INFO/SQLiteDatabaseAdapter(4692): DB (playlists.db) copied!
>   08-06 19:05:46.373: INFO/SQLiteDatabaseAdapter(4692): Try to create instance of database (playlists.db)
>   08-06 19:05:46.373: INFO/SQLiteDatabaseAdapter(4692): Create or Open database : playlists.db
>   08-06 19:05:46.389: INFO/SQLiteDatabaseAdapter(4692): instance of database (playlists.db) created !
>   08-06 19:05:46.389: INFO/Database(4692): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: playlist
>   08-06 19:05:46.397: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(4692): Shutting down VM
>   08-06 19:05:46.397: WARN/dalvikvm(4692): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7e0)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidworkz.andamp/com.androidworkz.andamp.andAMP}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: playlist: , while compiling: SELECT playlist.* FROM playlist ORDER BY id ASC;
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: playlist: , while compiling: SELECT playlist.* FROM playlist ORDER BY id ASC;
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at com.androidworkz.andamp.objects.Playlist.getPlaylists(Playlist.java:75)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at com.androidworkz.andamp.andAMP.onCreate(andAMP.java:353)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
>   08-06 19:05:46.514: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4692):     ... 11 more

Here is the dbhelper class

```
package com.androidworkz.andamp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Android's default system path for your application's database.
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.androidworkz.andamp/databases/";

private static String DB_NAME = "playlists.db";

public DBHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    if (!checkDataBaseExistence()) {
        createDatabase();
    }
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // Leave this method empty
}

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // fill in your code here
}

public void createDatabase() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    String dbPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    db.close();

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE [playlist] ("+
            "[id] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"+
            "[name] VARCHAR(255)  NULL);)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE [songs] ("+
            "[id] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,"+
            "[playlistId] INTEGER  NULL,"+
            "[songId] INTEGER  NULL,"+
            "[name] VARCHAR(255)  NULL,"+
            "[key] VARCHAR(255)  NULL,"+
            "[duration] INTEGER  NULL,"+
            "[path] VARCHAR(255)  NULL,"+
            "[artistName] VARCHAR(255)  NULL,"+
            "[artistKey] VARCHAR(255)  NULL,"+
            "[albumId] INTEGER  NULL,"+
            "[albumName] VARCHAR(255)  NULL,"+
            "[albumKey] VARCHAR(255)  NULL);");
    db.close();
}

private boolean checkDataBaseExistence() {

    // database to be verified
    SQLiteDatabase dbToBeVerified = null;

    try {
        // get database path
        String dbPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        // try to open the database
        dbToBeVerified = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // do nothing since the database does not exist
    }

    // in case it exists, close it
    if (dbToBeVerified != null) {
        // close DB
        dbToBeVerified.close();

    }

    // in case there is a DB entity, the DB exists
    return dbToBeVerified != null ? true : false;
}
}
```

god I hate this stupid "enter code here"... why can't stackoverflow just use tags like a normal syntax highlighter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 08-06 19:05:46.389: INFO/Database(4692): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: playlist

Are you sure the database is copying correctly, it appears as though the table doesn't exist?

Have you tried copying the data off the phone after execution via DDMS and exploring it to see if the schema is correct?

Comment: Yes... all of that. In fact... here is the db I pulled from the phone. http://www.androidworkz.com/playlists.db and (as I pointed out) it works perfectly on the 1.6 emulator.

Comment: @adnroidworkz Hmm that is odd, I haven't had a problem with my helpers spanning 1.6-2.2, can you post some of your SQLiteOpenHelper code, particularly accessing the DB? Maybe we can figure out the problem from there.

Comment: I appreciate the time you spent answering my question. I was able to fix the issue this morning. The problem appears to have been that I was using a databases that I had created with an external tool and when I opened the database in Eclipse it told me that one of the tables contained an invalid field type... so I changed the dbhelper class to create the database from scratch rather than copying it and that worked.

Comment: @androidworkz Glad to hear you got it resolved, I hadn't seen any issues copying a database from an existing but definitely good to know about!

Comment: well it appears I spoke too soon... it works in the 2.2 emulator but crashes on my phone... how annoying this has become. Is it the brackets around the names? []

Comment: @androidworkz That's a good question, I would have a hard time accepting it, but have you tried to remove them and see if there is any difference?  I double check some of my helpers to be sure and I'm not using sql quoting on the names at all.

Comment: God I feel stupid... the issue is that I was calling getWriteableDatabase from my adapter class but hadn't overridden the method to pass the db path... it's working now :P I am new to using sqlite and java in general... I have been a php developer for 10 years and a windows/m$ developer for 5 years before that and have alot of experience working with databases... I feel retarded for making such a simple mistake... lol

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that it can appear that you are missing tables if you try to access the table too soon after startup. There is a definite latency that you need to account for before you attempt to access the table. It drove me crazy.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm running into this as well. Did you resolve it? For example with a Thread.sleep()?

Comment: I think I'm running into this as well. Did you resolve it? I got a crash from a version of my app that takes a couple of minutes to download mp3 files before the user can even access the database.I think I'm running into this as well. Did you resolve it? I got a crash from a version of my app that takes a couple of minutes to download mp3 files before the user can even access the database.